# How to Pass value to the user defined class ( Jar file) from Jmeter?

Tags: jmeter

I am new to Jmeter. I have written one class with more methods to perform some encryption. I need to Pass value to that methods of class based on the response from Jmeter. Help on this is highly useful!

```
import java.security.Key;
import java.security.KeyFactory;
import java.security.PublicKey;
import java.security.spec.X509EncodedKeySpec;
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import android.util.Base64;

public  class Test2 {

String public_key;
String card_no;
public String getPublic_key() {
    return public_key;
}

public void setPublic_key(String public_key) {
    this.public_key = public_key;
}

public String getCard_no() {
    return card_no;
}

public void setCard_no(String card_no) {
    this.card_no = card_no;
}

public static String trimBegin(String public_key) {

    String trimmed_string = public_key.replaceFirst("-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----", "");
    return trimmed_string;
}

public static String trimEnd(String trimmed_string) {

    String trimmed_string1 = trimmed_string.replaceFirst("-----END PUBLIC KEY-----", "");
    return trimmed_string1;
}

public static String replace(String trimmed_string1) {
    String final_key=trimmed_string1.replaceAll("\n", "");
    return final_key;

}
```

}

I need to Pass value to the method trimBegin using jmeter and thereby accessing rest all methods

Comment: This is too broad. add some code and context

Comment: I have added code snippet. @user7294900

Comment: I added 2 solutions in my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Package your class a .jar file and put it along with all dependencies (especially `android.util.Base64`) to [JMeter Classpath](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#classpath)
2. Restart JMeter to pick the jar up
3. You should be able to invoke your `trimBegin` method from [JSR223 Test Elements](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223) like:

   ```
   String trimmed = Test2.trimBegin(ctx.getPreviousResult().getResponseDataAsString())
   ```

   This `ctx.getPreviousResult().getResponseDataAsString()` function returns result of the previous sampler.

---

Also be aware that starting from [JMeter version 4.0](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/whats-new-in-jmeter-4) you have [__digest() function](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__digest) so theoretically you don't have to go for any custom development.

Comment: Thanks @Dmitri . But i have response as like this : {"public key":"-----BEGIN----XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX----END-----","access token":"XXXXXXXXXXX"}. I need to extract only the public key part and its value.